# Populate hidden form element value with the value of a text field on form submit (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, forms

I want to automatically populate a hidden form element with the value of what is entered in a single line text field in a form when submitted. How would this be done with jQuery? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="" />
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="some.email@typed.here.on.webpage.com" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found this method to work well across browsers:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitMyForm(){
    $('#username').val($('#email').val());
    $('#myform').submit();
}
</script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform" action="http://www.example.com" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="" />
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="some.email@typed.here.on.webpage.com" />
</form>
<button class="submit"  onclick="submitMyForm()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A slightly cleaner solution would involve moving the onclick of the submit button away from the HTML - link up this event handler in the script block, inside the document ready function: $(function(){});

Comment: i.e. give the submit an id of "mySubmitButton" and then do this in the script: $(function() { $("").click(function(event){ submitMyForm(); }); })

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $('#username').val($('#email').val());
}
```

I believe most (if not all) browsers will have this fire before the data is packaged up and sent.  Give it a try.

Also give the form an ID and change `'form'` to `'#THEID'`

Reference for the submit event:

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Reading up on it now :)

Comment: Hi Bob, I was trying a similar solution, but for some reason the data isn't being submitted as expected. I'm using hidden fields, and updating them using the submit handler as you've suggested too. I expected it to just work, but I don't see the values being sent through in the POST :(

Comment: For those looking for an answer to this suggestion, I've found that altering the .submit(function() to a .click(function() while targeting the submit button as the trigger is what did it for me.