# Replace dots and commas in a field and then use that value to auto populate another field using jquery

Tags: jquery, field, auto-populate

I'm using Google Maps to calculate distance between cities. I need to use that distance value for some basic calculations. Distance has to be in "Angloamerican" format (1,234.00) but in metric system. So, Google Maps answer for Madrid - Berlin query will be one of these two:

```
a) <span jscontent="distance['text']" jsdisplay="distance" jstcache="7">2.320,1 km</span>
b) <span jscontent="distance.text" jstcache="23">2.320,1 km</span>
```

Please notice the differences in span "classes" (jstcache is 7 or 23) and lack of any "id" or "name" attributes.

What I want to accomplish is:

1) Convert these Google Maps distance values to "Angloamerican" format (2,320 km) or (even better) format without thousands separator which would only use dots as decimal separator (2320.1 km)

2) Use that filtered value to populate a text field called distance

I searched all over the web, but didn't find the exact answer. This post was the most helpful:

[Populate hidden form element value with the value of a text field on form submit (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103524/populate-hidden-form-element-value-with-the-value-of-a-text-field-on-form-submit)

It helped me a bit with the auto-populate part, but I can't make it work in combination with this Google Maps code. Here is my current code:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitMyForm(){
$('#distance').val($('jstcache^=7').val());
$('#Googlemap').submit();
}
</script>
...
</head>

<body>
...
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" id="distance" name="distance" value="" />
</form>
...
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

To grab the value:

```
var dist = $('span[jstcache=7]').val();
```

To localize:

```
var parts = dist.split(',');
dist = parts[0].replace('.','') + '.' + parseInt(parts[1],10);
```

Comment: No, that is not intended. Actually, I want to grab a value jstcache=7 or jstcache=23. Or use "jscontent=.." values. That is the one of the problems, Google Maps total distance is printed this way, enclosed in such code and I'm not sure what is the best way to pull that value.

Comment: @Marco, I just made it a plain `=` in that case (updated). Note that the selector is for a `span` whose `jstcache` attribute is `7` -- *not* a `jstcache` element.

Comment: It's not working. I have pasted the whole page code underneath, maybe something else is missing

Comment: Now I did manage to pull the value using Luke's code. The problem was this part: <form id="Googlemap" action="#" onsubmit="calcRoute(); return false" onclick="submitMyForm()">   Therefore I have to click somewhere in the form after searching the route and then the value is displayed in the "distance" field. I am not sure which value would be better, mousemove? And is there a way to strip "km" part in the field? It would be great to have "10" instead of "10 km"

Comment: @Marco, I added a `parseInt()` -- one way of stripping out the non-numeric pieces.

Comment: @Ken Redler Ok, I have changed the code to your version, but nothing is displayed in "distance" field. Here is the code, I'm not sure about "dist" and "val" part: <script type="text/javascript">
function submitMyForm(){
var dist = $('span[jsdisplay=distance]').val();

var parts = dist.split(',');
dist = parts[0].replace('.','') + '.' + parseInt(parts[1],10);


    $('#distance').dist(val);
    $('#Googlemap').submit();
}
</script>  You'll notice that I changed jstcache to jsdisplay=distance because that part remains fixed (jstcache value can be 7 or 16).

Comment: @Marco, try `$('#distance').val(dist)`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can do this with the javascript string .replace() function. In this case, it's a little trickier because you're doing a swap: periods for commas, commas for periods. This means you have to use an intermediate value. A working example using underscores would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitMyForm(){
    var val = $('[jstcache=7]').text(); // get text content of <span jstcache="7">

    // Replace using regex instead of strings, to catch more than the first match
    val = val.replace(/\./g, "_");
    val = val.replace(/,/g, ".");
    val = val.replace(/_/g, ",");

    $('#distance').val(val);
    $('#Googlemap').submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Leave out `val = val.replace("_", ",");` and change `"_"` in the first replace to `""` to get 'even better' format.

Comment: Correct you are. I swapped what the "even better" was in my head, I thought commas were desired for some reason. :)

Comment: This one is also not working, I have pasted my "whole" code underneath